# Cron job to delete catalog_product_entity_datetime table data, am I using the correct interface?

Tags: magento2, cron, query, interface

I have a query to select data from catalog_product_entity_datetime table.
can I use below interface to grab the data from above table? If can't what should I do to grab data from this table?

I don't get it how to use below interface to grab data without specify which table?

```
`use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`;
```

my query,

```
SELECT  * FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime`
WHERE `attribute_id` IN (22,33) AND `store_id` IN (1, 2);
```

Delete return rolls from above query.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php

namespace ABC\CleanSpecial\Cron;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class Deleteresult {

  protected $logger;
  protected $timezone;
  protected $productCollection;

  public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    Collection $productCollection
  ) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
  }

  public function execute() {
    $collection = $this->productCollection->create();
    $getAttributeIdData= array(22,33);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_id',array('in'=> $getAttributeIdData ));
    $getStoreIdData= array(1,2);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id',array('in'=> $getStoreIdData ));   
    $deleteRows = $collection->count();
    $collection->walk('delete');
    $date = $this->timezone->date()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    $this->logger->info($deleteRows.' rows deleted from catalog_product_entity_datetime table at '.$date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you use a product collection, you are basically 'asking' for the data on specific filtered products (or all products if you don't apply any filters). You are not specifying where to look for the data, you rather specify which data you need and based on the internal EAV structure, Magento knows where to look (you don't need to specify the attribute_ids, you rather use attribute_codes instead).

There is also a major difference between the methods `addAttributeToFilter()` and `addAttributeToSelect()`. If you are interested in getting the data only for specific products under specific conditions, then you use *addAttributeToFilter()*, but when you are interested in grabbing the data registered on specific attributes, you need to use *addAttributeToSelect()*.

So if you are interested in grabbing the data for specific products on specific datetime attributes (with attribute codes say *datetime1* and *datetime2*), you do something like this:

```php
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('datetime1')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('datetime2')
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

then you can iterate the items and unset the values from your datetime attributes:

```php
$products = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $product->unsetData('datetime1');
   $product->unsetData('datetime2');
   $product->save();
}
```

---

2. Or you could use a different approach and use direct database queries (code is untested, but should be about right - **use it on a test environment anyway**):
   your class needs to use the following

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
```

and inject `$this->resourceConnection = \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;` in the constructor.
then, in your `execute()` method:

```php
public function execute()
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
    $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_datetime');

    $connection->delete(
          $tableName, 
          [
             'attribute_id IN (?)' => [22, 23],
             'store_id IN (?)' => [1,2]
          ]
    );

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Its work as I expected

Comment: hey there! you are most welcome :) which method did you use?

Comment: I did use the 2nd method